# Where can I find a lawyer for victims of cyberstalking?

Tags: internet

Where can I find a lawyer for victims of cyberstalking? One can find a criminal defense lawyer but not the one help these victims.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may search for attorneys at:https://www.martindale.com/.
2. On the web site above, you may use the following search terms to locate attorneys who may be practicing Victim Law, Internet Crime litigation.

   Victim Law
   Victim Rights
   Internet Crime
3. Victims of crime usually do not seek  Criminal Defense attorneys, the accused/defendants do.
4. From the question, it appears that the Victims of an alleged Cyber Crime is seeking counsel. Generally, Victims of Crime may be eligible for free services from the State where the crime occurred..
5. The National Crime Victim Bar Association (NCVBA) offers victims of crime free referrals to attorneys for consultation. 
   http://victimsofcrime.org/our-programs/national-crime-victim-bar-association/for-victims

Comment: Often victims of crime would seek a trial lawyer (i.e. someone who does plaintiff's tort claims) or general practice lawyer, who is familiar with the Internet to bring a tort claim against the perpetrator, to seek a TRO, or to assist of making a persuasive case to criminal prosecutors to press the case (a difficult thing to do).

Comment: "Victims of Crime may be eligible for free services from the State where the crime occurred" Would you explain the next step?

Comment: Most states have enacted Victim Compensation laws which pays for bills and expenses that result from certain violent crimes or have been injured or have been threatened with injury. As a result of Cyberstalking,if a person is injured, the victim could apply for these services and the State pays for the covered services.

Comment: I have contacted various organizations with written documents but I have not heard back.